# DH parameters to compute the transformation matrix

Tags: dh-parameters

Below is my code. All values of theta, d, a and alpha are known. 
How should I define T00, T01, and so on?

function [T] = dhtransform(theta, d, a, alpha)

T = [cosd(theta) -sind(theta) * cosd(alpha) sind(theta) * sind(alpha) a * cosd(theta);
     sind(theta) cosd(theta) * cosd(alpha)  -cosd(theta) * sind(alpha) a * sind(theta);
     0,sind(alpha),cosd(alpha),d;
     0,0,0,1];

end

T00 = [1 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0; 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1];
T01 = dhtransform(30, 10.25, 0, 90 );
T12 = dhtransform(45, 0, 9, 0);
T23 = dhtransform(-90,0, 9, 0);
T34 = dhtransform(45,0, 0, 90);
T45 = dhtransform(60, 6.25, 0, 0);

Endeffector = T00 * T01 * T12 * T23 * T34 * T45;

end

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* JJL, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Also, please use MathJax to make your math easier to read.  Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference